# For which values of integer $k$, does the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz$ have positive integer solutions $(x, y, z)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, problem-solving, integers

For which values of integer $k$, does the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz$ have positive integer solutions $(x, y, z)$

I immediately thought of saying that from symmetry we have that $x\le y \le z$.

Also, $y^2+z^2 \equiv 0 mod x$, $x^2+z^2\equiv 0mody$ and $x^2+y^2\equiv 0modz$.

Moreover through trial and error I worked out that the solutions for $k$ must be $k=1$ or $k=3$ but I have not managed to prove it. I attempted to use inequalities, but that didn't work out either. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: For $k=2$ there a re no solutions, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851751/prove-that-x2y2z2-2xyz-has-no-answer-over-bbbn?noredirect=1&lq=1). The case $k=3$ is called "Markoff's equation". Obviously then $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ is a solution.

Comment: The triple $(5,29,433)$ is a solution for $k=3$, and there are many more. There are no solutions $x\leq y\leq z\leq1000$ with $k\geq4$. Maybe you should try to prove that $k\geq4$ is impossible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry I meant to write k=3 editing it now

Comment: @ChristianBlatter sorry I meant to write k=3 editing it now

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  complete proof in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf

Comment: @DietrichBurde complete proof in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  I have been able to use the main idea, that of looking for fundamental solutions, for many problems on this site that amount to "Vieta Jumping."

Comment: @WillJagy Very nice, thank you! Even in German!

Comment: @WillJagy I understood only *Zahl*, which is the origin of the symbol $\mathbb{Z}$ for integers. Can you confirm?

Comment: @WillJagy I do not understand German. Could you please explain the solution in english?

Comment: @Michael Blane Assuming $(x,y,z)=(x0,y0,z0)$ is a smallest solution and $x0 \geq y0 \geq z0$.
Then we can say that $k \leq 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called a CW answer; recommend beginning with

[Equation with Vieta Jumping: $(x+y+z)^2=nxyz$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/1930796#1930796)

Here are a number of posts  about
Vieta Jumping/ Hurwitz/Markov         Grundlösung

[Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $xy \mid x^2+y^2+1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/let-x-and-y-be-positive-integers-such-that-xy-mid-x2y21?rq=1)

[Diophantine quartic equation in four variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632097/diophantine-quartic-equation-in-four-variables/632178#632178)

[Is it true that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-t}$ has only finitely many distinct positive integer values with $x$, $y$ positive integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829228/is-it-true-that-fx-y-dfracx2y2xy-t-has-only-finitely-many-distinct-i/1480206#1480206)  !!!!!!!!!  +++++++

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411049/if-a-b-are-positive-integers-and-ab-1-mid-a%C2%B2-b%C2%B2-then-prove-that-q

[Proving that all terms in sequence are positive integers (Recursive)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415252/proving-that-all-terms-in-sequence-are-positive-integers-recursive/1415304#1415304)

[Diophantine equation $(x+y)(x+y+1) - kxy = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417404/diophantine-equation-xyxy1-kxy-0)

[Find the postive integers such $xy+x+y\mid x^2+y^2-2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462435/find-the-postive-integers-such-xyxy-mid-x2y2-2)

[Find the integer values of c](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478289/find-the-integer-values-of-c)

[Find all solutions to the diophantine equation $(x+2)(y+2)(z+2)=(x+y+z+2)^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604292/find-all-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-x2y2z2-xyz22/1604582#1604582)

[Characterize the integers $a,b$ satisfying: $ab-1|a^2+b^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780420/characterize-the-integers-a-b-satisfying-ab-1a2b2/1781381#1781381)

[Equation with Vieta Jumping: $(x+y+z)^2=nxyz$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/1930796#1930796)     Follows Hurwitz very closely!!  (x+y+z)^2 = nxyz

[Showing that $m^2-n^2+1$ is a square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188567/showing-that-m2-n21-is-a-square/2193043#2193043)  LEMMA +

[Showing that $m^2-n^2+1$ is a square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188567/showing-that-m2-n21-is-a-square/2193944#2193944)   LEMMA -

[How prove infinitely many postive integers triples $(x,y,z)$ such $(x+y+z)^2+2(x+y+z)=5(xy+yz+zx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399830/how-prove-infinitely-many-postive-integers-triples-x-y-z-such-xyz22x/2400509#2400509)

[Find all possible value of c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664145/find-all-possible-value-of-c/2668331#2668331)

[What are the solutions of the equation $3np+3n+2=n^2+p^2$, with n and p positive integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818849/what-are-the-solutions-of-the-equation-3np3n2-n2p2-with-n-and-p-positive/2818883#2818883)

[Prove there is no $x, y \in \mathbb Z^+ \text{ satisfying } \frac{x}{y} +\frac{y+1}{x}=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853669/prove-there-is-no-x-y-in-mathbb-z-text-satisfying-fracxy-fracy/2853742#2853742)

[Integer points on a hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869251/integer-points-on-a-hyperbola/2869365#2869365) two spiral arms

[$m+n+p-1=2\sqrt{mnp}$ in positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955986/mnp-1-2-sqrtmnp-in-positive-integers)

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1726220_if_fraction_integer_then_equal_to_5   Poland 1991 training