# Integers solutions of modified Markoff equation with parameter $k\in\mathbb{N}$ : $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = kpqr$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I recently studied the Markoff equation :
\begin{equation*}
p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = 3pqr
\end{equation*}
And I think I've heard that there are solutions iff $k = 1$ or $3$ but I can't prove it.
I manage to show that there are solutions of the form $(p,p,r)$ iif $k = 1$ or $3$ but that's not enough.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For which values of integer $k$, does the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz$ have positive integer solutions $(x, y, z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978735/for-which-values-of-integer-k-does-the-equation-x2y2z2-kxyz-have-posit) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2%2Bq%5E2%2Br%5E2%3Dkpqr%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). There are also several AoPS threads, e.g., [x^2 + y + z^2 = nxyz in positive integers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2053160p14599925), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Solution by VJ](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1946119p13415734), [Find k if x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz don't have any integer solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h351065p1891658), etc.

Comment: see http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf    which proves it.  Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Answer (score 0):

Here is the page of outcomes in the 1907 article by Hurwitz. He has already shown that the collection of integer solutions to $$x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2  = x x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$$  arises from a single fundamental solution; those are listed for $n \leq 10.$

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For, $k=3$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz$

Above has parametric solution:

$x=2w^2-2w+1$

$y=5w^2-4w+1$

$z=29w^4-48w^3+34w^2-12w+2$

For,  $w=2$ we get:

$(x,y,z)=(5,13,194)$

---